# Input shape for LSTM which has one hot encoded data

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, time-series

The sample dataset contains Location point of the user.

```
df.head()

   user           tslot         Location_point
0   0   2015-12-04 13:00:00     4356
1   0   2015-12-04 13:15:00     4356
2   0   2015-12-04 13:30:00     3659
3   0   2015-12-04 13:45:00     4356
4   0   2015-12-04 14:00:00     8563

df.shape 

(288,3)
```

As the location points are categorical values they are one hot encoded.

```
encoded = to_categorical(df['Location_point'])
```

The encoded values are as below

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Shape of the encoded values is (288,8564).

I tried to shape the training data

```
X_trai = []
y_trai = []
for i in range(96, 288):
    X_trai.append(encoded[i-96:i])
    y_trai.append(encoded[i])
X_trai, y_trai = np.array(X_trai), np.array(y_trai)

X_trai = np.reshape(X_trai, (X_trai.shape[0], X_trai.shape[1], 1))
```

And the model is

```
regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_trai.shape[1], 1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

regressor.fit(X_trai, y_trai, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32)
```

This is not the correct model. I am new to deep learning. I tried to see some example but not able to understand for one hot encoding. I would be grateful if someone can explain the input shape, output shape, and the correct model.

```
The input is the sequence of the location points and the output is to predict
 the next location point for that user.
```

Comment: Also, can you please post the error. I think it requires 3 Dimensional shape of the input.

Comment: yeah, but I don't get how to convert my data to 3 dimensional. can you suggest my input based on my data,

Comment: Can you post the error.

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_3_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 288, 8654). The error is regarding the shape of the input.

Answer (score 4):

The input shape depends on your data, if you have a single sample with 288 timesteps and 8564 features, your input shape will be (batch_size=1, timesteps=288, n_features=8564), if you have 288 samples of a single timestep it wold be (batch_size=288, timesteps=1, n_features=8564).

Anyway, here you have a tutorial about how to prepare your data for LSTM models.
https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/

The input shape for the LSTM is the following:

3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim), (Optional) 2D tensors with shape (batch_size, output_dim).

**Timesteps** will be your time-series sequences length and **input_dim** the number of features you have, in this case since they are one hot encoded it would be 8564.

The output shape will depend on the architecture of your model.

- The first layer gives you an output of (batch_size, timesteps, units)
- The sencond layer: (batch_size, timesteps, units)
- The third layer:(batch_size, units)
- The last layer: (batch_size, 1)

Nevertheless, you can check your model input/output shapes with:

regressor.input_shape & regressor.output_shape

Lastly, why don't you consider your Location_point as a numeric variable?

Comment: Hello @kevin, Sorry for the late reply. I went through the book you mentioned above but couldn't find the solution to my problem. I tried all the input shapes but failed. I cannot consider Location point as numerical values. while predicting the values the model output random values but the location points are specific categorical values which should be predicted using one hot encoding. Can you write the input shape in detail? Let me know if there is anything. Thanks